# stop method for function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have small function that adds class to elements in array every 100ms

```
  var index = 0;
  var $pcs = $('.participant');

  var setWinCls = {
    start: function(i){
      if(i>0){
        $pcs.eq(i-1).removeClass('winner');
      }
      if(i == $pcs.length){
        i=0;
      }
      $pcs.eq(i).addClass('winner');
      setTimeout(function() { setWinCls.start(i+1) },100);
    },
    stop: function () {
      ...
    }
  };
```

I'm trying to define stop method with will stop adding class on elements and stops on last added element or element I will point. Any suggestions? 
I tried use `return false` but it didn't helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a flag (`stopped`) to `setWinCls`, and use the `stop` method to change it to `true`. As long as `stopped` is `false`, the `setTimeout` will be called:

```
var $pcs = $('.participant');

var setWinCls = {
  stopped: false, // the flag
  start: function(i) {
    if (i > 0) {
      $pcs.eq(i - 1).removeClass('winner');
    }
    if (i == $pcs.length) {
      i = 0;
    }
    $pcs.eq(i).addClass('winner');

    // if stopped is false, setTimeout will be called
    this.stopped || setTimeout(function() {
      setWinCls.start(i + 1)
    }, 100);
  },
  stop: function() {
    this.stopped = true; // changing stopped to true
  }
};
```